# Updating GraphQL Query With New Variables

Tags: meteor, leaflet, graphql, react-apollo

I have a GraphQL query from Apollo + React that I am using on a map component where the parameters are "latitude" and "longitude".  The variables are provided by the map's center point and I am trying to get it to update the query as the center point or zoom level is changed but can't find a "simple" way to do this - maybe I am overthinking things.

Is there a way to simply say, here's some new variables, refetch me new data?  The only approach I have seen so far is related to mutations but this seems like it is used more for inserting new values.  Any ideas or suggestions would be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds quite confused.

If I understand correctly, you would like to send a new GraphQL query whenever the map view (center and/or zoom level) changes.

In that case, you would simply listen to the Leaflet map's [`'moveend'`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-moveend) and [`'zoomend'`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-zoomend) events and re-send your query based on the new map center and zoom (I would say that view port bounds would probably be more appropriate).

Comment: thanks for your reply!

the parent component is using the below and the child component is refetching until loading completes.  after 'moveend' events from leaflet, what is the simplest way to update the lat/long variables in the graphql query?

        MapWithData = graphql(gql
            `{
                waterSystemsNearby(long:123456,lat:123456,distance:1000) {
                    LATITUDE
                    LONGITUDE
                    WATER_SYSTEM_NAME
                }
            }`

    }
...
return (<MapWithData />)